# How do I measure a custom native component in React Native on Android

Tags: android, react-native, measure

I want to create a custom native component which renders a single line of text. The length of this text is dynamic and the typeface and size are configurable.

When I place my custom component in a standard `<View />` the provided size constraints in `View.onMeasure` (native) are zero for height and this is `MeasureSpec.EXACTLY`. Returning any non-zero height in `View.onMeasure` does nothing.

```
class App extends React.Component<{}, undefined> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{
          flex: 1,
        }}>
        <CustomComponent />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

How do I allow my custom native view to measure itself and provide this to React Native during measurement and layout?

Comment: Have you tried "minHeight" ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After much time and effort I found the answer.

You need to override `ViewManager.getShadowNodeClass` and provide a custom implementation of `ReactShadowNode`.

Like so;

```
public class CustomShadowNode extends LayoutShadowNode implements YogaMeasureFunction {
    public CustomShadowNode() {
        this.setMeasureFunction(this);
    }

    @Override
    public long measure(
      YogaNode node,
      float width, YogaMeasureMode widthMode,
      float height, YogaMeasureMode heightMode) {
      return YogaMeasureOutput.make(0, 0);
    }
}
```

I used `LayoutShadowNode` as it appears to handle the standard layout and styling props.

I wrote more detail on the matter [here](https://nicholasmarais1158.github.io/2017/07/React-Native-Custom-Measuring).

Comment: I'm trying this for myself, and I'm not even finding the getting the constructor of my shadow node called, much less the measure function.

Comment: Thank you soooo much for shedding light on this.
I'm currently in a situation where I'm trying to measure an android Native UI Component that extends `ReactRootView`, but neither `onLayout`, nor `onMeasure` seem to be running, therefore the component remains invisible.

Any idea what I can do to measure it?

Thanks

Comment: I've not tried extending `ReactRootView` with this approach. Perhaps there is some logic which makes this view work differently. I suggest raising your issue as a new question, and linking to this question to provide some background.